# Generate dynamic tests based on a parameter in Nightwatch

Tags: testing, automated-tests, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I'm using NightwatchJS to automate the test on our reporting website.

This is my actual code:

```
module.exports = {
  '@tags': ['Report 1','base','full'],
  'Report 1' : function (browser) {
    checkAnalisi(browser, 'report1', 1, 2015, '767.507')
  }
};

function checkAnalisi(browser, nomeAnalisi, scheda, year, risultatoAtteso){
  return browser
      .url('https://example.com/Wizard?analisi=' + nomeAnalisi)
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 5000)
      .selectScheda(scheda-1) //Seleziona la scheda (0-based)
      .selectPromptValue('Year', year)
      .selectRappresentazione('Table')
      .waitForElementVisible('table', 5000, true)
      .assert.containsText('table tr:last-child td:last-child', risultatoAtteso)
      .end();
}
```

I made some helper commands to select different things in the page:

`.selectScheda(scheda-1)
 .selectPromptValue('Year', year)
 .selectRappresentazione('Table')`

`selectPromptValue` wants a prompt name and the value to set it in the page.

For now the function only sets the year parameter but in my reports I also have different parameters.

What I want to do is to pass an object to the `checkAnalisi` function to dynamically generate test. For example if I want to set different prompt values I want to pass something like `[['Year', 2015],['Another prompt','another value']]` and the `checkAnalisi` function should add 2 `.selectPromptValue` steps with the respective values.

Is it possible to cycle an input array in my function to add more steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was able to solve this easily directly in my `selectPromptValue` custom command.

I simply added the new parameter to the checkAnalisi function like this (promptValues is the new parameter):

```
function checkAnalisi(browser, nomeAnalisi, scheda, promptValues, risultatoAtteso){
  return browser
      .url('https://example.com/Wizard?analisi=' + nomeAnalisi)
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 5000)
      .selectScheda(scheda-1) //Seleziona la scheda (0-based)
      .selectPromptValue(promptValues)
      .selectRappresentazione('Table')
      .waitForElementVisible('table', 5000, true)
      .assert.containsText('table tr:last-child td:last-child', risultatoAtteso)
      .end();
}
```

I then modified the selectPromptValue.js custom command like this:

```
exports.command = function(v) {
    for(var i=0; i<v.length; i++){
        this.execute('$("#"+$("label:visible:contains(\'' + v[i][0] + '\')").attr("for")).val("' + v[i][1] + '")');
    }
    return this;
};
```